# if then else statement to find files

Tags: bash

Hello how can i use the if/else statement to look for files. Lets say if i have a `file.txt` in root, i want to be able to write a scrip that says `if [ file.txt ]` does not exist then use the `find / -newer sshh > file.txt` and or else use `[file.txt]` and then mail the changes if anything has changed.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, `-f` will tell you if a file exists.

```
if [ -f /file.txt ];
  then
    // do something with mail
  else
    // do something with find
fi
```

Comment: Sorry, left out the spaces inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt really tell us a lot about your platform, but IMHO - if you don't know how to do something like this off the top of your head with find and basic shell builtins - you should probably use a higher level language. It will be easier to conceptualize and easier to maintain.

Take it as a learning experience - a change to experiment with python, perl or a language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
if test -e "file.txt"; then
  cat file.txt | mail -s "file.txt changed" example@example.com
else
  find / -newer sshh > file.txt
fi
```

But you most likely want to combine it with `diff` to find out if the file structure changed.

Comment: You get a “Useless Use of Cat” award for that.